# Ошибка при парсинге json

Tags: json, qt5, парсер

Всем привет.

qt5, пытаюсь парсить json, используя либу qjson:

```
    QJson::Parser parser;
    QByteArray json;
    json.append("{\"param\":\"test\"}");
    bool ok;       
    QVariantMap result = parser.parse(json, &ok).toMap();
```

В ответ ругается:

```
    QBuffer::open: Buffer access not specified
    QIODevice::write: device not open
    QIODevice::seek: The device is not open
    QBuffer::open: Buffer access not specified
```

Как быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблемма возникает вследствие некорректного открытия потока для чтения внутри самой библиотеки. Создал [пул-реквест](https://github.com/flavio/qjson/pull/54) в репозитории автора.

Для самостоятельного разрешения ситуации просто замените в файле `src/parser.cpp` внутри исходников библиотеки строку

```
QVariant Parser::parse(const QByteArray& jsonString, bool* ok) {
  QBuffer buffer;
  buffer.open(QBuffer::ReadWrite); // <--- ага, вот эти ребята
  buffer.write(jsonString);
  buffer.seek(0);
  return parse (&buffer, ok);
}
```

на строку

```
buffer.open(QBuffer::ReadWrite | QBuffer::Text);
```

И пересоберите библиотеку.